# Why can't Swift infer base string with specific indexing string methods?

Tags: swift, string, indexing

Here's something I don't really understand:  Swift is soooo good at "inferring things" ... yet, the syntax of strings, say:

```
hello[hello.index(after: startIndex)]
```

requires the second hello!  No "other string" makes sense!  Why can't the language be updated to work like this?

```
hello[  .index(after: startIndex) ]
```

There are times when you must retype the base string name three or four times in single line of code!

Comment: I don't know swift syntax, but I can definitely think of times when I would want to index one string by information from another... (but this does seem like a common use-case).

Answer (score 3):

You would like something like this

```
let red: UIColor = UIColor.red
```

that can also be written as

```
let red: UIColor = .red
```

However in this case `.red` is a **Type Property** of `UIColor`.

> `.red` is something that does belong to the `UIColor` type, not to a particolar instance.

That's why you can omit `UIColor` in the second snippet. Because Swift knows `.red` is inside the `UIColor` class.

### Let's get back to your example

Here

```
hello.index(after: hello.startIndex)
```

cannot become

```
hello.index(after: .startIndex)
```

because in this case `startIndex` is **NOT** a Type Property. It's a property related to that specific value `hello`.